# Remapped colon key not show command-line mode immediately

Tags: lua, config, neovim

Map semicolon to colon

```
local opts = { silent = true }
keymap("n", ";", ":", opts)
```

This works fine but not show command-line mode immediately after I just press semicolon. Actually it's already in command-line mode now but not showing in the status line until I press another key
[image]

Comment: Can not reproduce. can you reproduce with `nvim --clean`? It is likely caused by your other configs, you need to debug yourself.

Comment: @jdhao problems solved by remove the silent option.

Comment: ah, this is the reason. I actually have met it before, but I kinda forgot, see the [issue here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6832). In short, it make no sense to use `silent` for mapping involved with command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the silent option solved the issue.